# Fan running continously on HP Pavillion G6 notebook with 12.04.1 LTS, help please?

Tags: fan, temperature

Fan is running continously on my HP Pavillion G6 notebook with 12.04.1 LTS. My system specifications are:-

Ram: 6Gb
Graphics Card:- 1 GB (AMD Raedon 64XX).
HDD: 540 GB.

[image: top command result]

[image: temp sensor live results]

Please find a list of ACPI errors logs from dmesg as follows:-

```
buffer@ankit:~$ dmesg | grep ACPI -i [    0.000000]  BIOS-e820: 000000009cebf000 - 000000009cfbf000 (ACPI NVS) [    0.000000]  BIOS-e820: 000000009cfbf000 - 000000009cfff000 (ACPI data) [   
0.000000] ACPI: RSDP 00000000000fe020 00024 (v02 HPQOEM) [    0.000000] ACPI: XSDT 000000009cffe120 00084 (v01 HPQOEM SLIC-MPC 00000001      01000013) [    0.000000] ACPI: FACP 000000009cffc000 000F4 (v04 HPQOEM SLIC-MPC 00000001 MSFT 01000013) [    0.000000] ACPI: DSDT 000000009cfec000 0C132 (v01 HP     1670     00000000 MSFT 01000013) [    0.000000] ACPI: FACS 000000009cf6c000 00040 [   
0.000000] ACPI: ASF! 000000009cffd000 000A5 (v32 HP     1670     00000001 MSFT 01000013) [    0.000000] ACPI: HPET 000000009cffb000 00038 (v01 HP     1670     00000001 MSFT 01000013) [    0.000000] ACPI: APIC 000000009cffa000 0008C (v02 HP     1670     00000001 MSFT 01000013) [    0.000000] ACPI: MCFG 000000009cff9000 0003C (v01 HP     1670     00000001 MSFT 01000013) [    0.000000] ACPI: SLIC 000000009cfeb000 00176 (v01 HPQOEM SLIC-MPC 00000001 MSFT 01000013) [ 
0.000000] ACPI: SSDT 000000009cfea000 00D52 (v01 HP     1670     00001000 MSFT 01000013) [    0.000000] ACPI: BOOT 000000009cfe8000 00028 (v01 HP     1670     00000001 MSFT 01000013) [    0.000000] ACPI: ASPT 000000009cfe5000 00034 (v07 HP     1670     00000001 MSFT 01000013) [    0.000000] ACPI: SSDT 000000009cfe4000 00780 (v01 HP     1670     00003000 INTL 20100121) [    0.000000] ACPI: SSDT 000000009cfe3000 00996 (v01 HP     1670     00003000 INTL 20100121) [ 
0.000000] ACPI: SSDT 000000009cfdd000 0219F (v01 HP     1670     00001000 INTL 20100121) [    0.000000] ACPI: Local APIC address 0xfee00000 [    0.000000] ACPI: PM-Timer IO Port: 0x408 [    0.000000] ACPI: Local APIC address 0xfee00000 [    0.000000] ACPI: LAPIC (acpi_id[0x01] lapic_id[0x00] enabled) [    0.000000] ACPI: LAPIC (acpi_id[0x02] lapic_id[0x01] enabled) [    0.000000] ACPI: LAPIC (acpi_id[0x03] lapic_id[0x02] enabled) [    0.000000] ACPI: LAPIC (acpi_id[0x04] lapic_id[0x03] enabled) [    0.000000] ACPI: LAPIC (acpi_id[0x05] lapic_id[0x00] disabled) [    0.000000] ACPI: LAPIC (acpi_id[0x06] lapic_id[0x00] disabled) [    0.000000] ACPI: LAPIC (acpi_id[0x07] lapic_id[0x00] disabled) [    0.000000] ACPI: LAPIC (acpi_id[0x08] lapic_id[0x00] disabled) [    0.000000] ACPI: IOAPIC (id[0x00] address[0xfec00000] gsi_base[0]) [    0.000000] ACPI: INT_SRC_OVR (bus 0 bus_irq 0 global_irq 2 dfl dfl) [    0.000000] ACPI: INT_SRC_OVR (bus 0 bus_irq 9 global_irq 9 high level) [   
0.000000] ACPI: IRQ0 used by override. [    0.000000] ACPI: IRQ2 used by override. [    0.000000] ACPI: IRQ9 used by override. [   
0.000000] Using ACPI (MADT) for SMP configuration information [    0.000000] ACPI: HPET id: 0x8086a201 base: 0xfed00000 [    0.005902] ACPI: Core revision 20110623 [    0.536006] PM: Registering ACPI NVS region at 9cebf000 (1048576 bytes) [    0.538423] ACPI FADT declares the system doesn't support PCIe ASPM, so disable it [    0.538429] ACPI: bus type pci registered [    0.656088] ACPI: Added _OSI(Module Device) [    0.656094] ACPI: Added _OSI(Processor Device) [   
0.656098] ACPI: Added _OSI(3.0 _SCP Extensions) [    0.656103] ACPI: Added _OSI(Processor Aggregator Device) [    0.660335] ACPI: EC: Look up EC in DSDT [    0.664416] ACPI: Executed 1 blocks of module-level executable AML code [    0.728303] [Firmware Bug]: ACPI: BIOS
_OSI(Linux) query ignored [    0.729536] ACPI: SSDT 000000009ce70798 00727 (v01  PmRef  Cpu0Cst 00003001 INTL 20100121) [    0.730622] ACPI: Dynamic OEM Table Load: [    0.730630] ACPI: SSDT           (null) 00727 (v01  PmRef  Cpu0Cst 00003001 INTL 20100121) [   
0.760829] ACPI: SSDT 000000009ce71a98 00303 (v01  PmRef    ApIst 00003000 INTL 20100121) [    0.761992] ACPI: Dynamic OEM Table Load: [
0.761998] ACPI: SSDT           (null) 00303 (v01  PmRef    ApIst 00003000 INTL 20100121) [    0.792451] ACPI: SSDT 000000009ce6fd98 00119 (v01  PmRef    ApCst 00003000 INTL 20100121) [    0.793521] ACPI: Dynamic OEM Table Load: [    0.793528] ACPI: SSDT           (null) 00119 (v01  PmRef    ApCst 00003000 INTL 20100121) [   
0.872981] ACPI: Interpreter enabled [    0.872992] ACPI: (supports S0 S3 S4 S5) [    0.873064] ACPI: Using IOAPIC for interrupt routing [   
0.882723] ACPI: EC: GPE = 0x16, I/O: command/status = 0x66, data = 0x62 [    0.883072] ACPI: No dock devices found. [    0.883084] PCI: Using host bridge windows from ACPI; if necessary, use "pci=nocrs" and report a bug [    0.883882] ACPI: PCI Root Bridge [PCI0] (domain 0000 [bus 00-fe]) [    0.924187] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Routing Table [\_SB_.PCI0._PRT] [    0.924509] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Routing Table [\_SB_.PCI0.RP01._PRT] [    0.924581] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Routing Table [\_SB_.PCI0.RP02._PRT] [    0.924659] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Routing Table [\_SB_.PCI0.RP03._PRT] [    0.924758] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Routing Table [\_SB_.PCI0.PEG0._PRT] [    0.924973]  pci0000:00: Requesting ACPI _OSC control (0x1d) [    0.925064]  pci0000:00: ACPI _OSC request failed (AE_ERROR), returned control mask: 0x1d [    0.925069] ACPI _OSC control for PCIe not granted, disabling ASPM [    0.930212] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKA] (IRQs 1 3 4 5 6 10 *11 12 14 15) [    0.930327] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKB] (IRQs 1 3 4 5 6 10 *11 12 14 15) [    0.930436] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKC] (IRQs 1 3 4 5 6 10 *11 12 14 15) [    0.930547] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKD] (IRQs 1 3 4 5 6 *10 11 12 14 15) [   
0.930655] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKE] (IRQs 1 3 4 5 6 10 11 12 14 15) *0, disabled. [    0.930764] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKF] (IRQs 1 3 4 5 6 10 11 12 14 15) *0, disabled. [    0.930873] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKG] (IRQs 1 3 4 5 6 10 *11 12 14 15) [    0.930979] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKH] (IRQs 1 3 4 5 6 10 11 12 14 15) *0, disabled. [    0.932142] PCI: Using ACPI for IRQ routing [   
0.967119] pnp: PnP ACPI init [    0.967151] ACPI: bus type pnp registered [    0.968356] pnp 00:00: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0a08 PNP0a03 (active) [    0.968516] pnp 00:01: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0200 (active) [    0.968586] pnp 00:02: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs INT0800 (active) [    0.968818] pnp 00:03: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0103 (active) [    0.968915] pnp 00:04: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0c04 (active) [    0.969206] system 00:05: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0c02 (active) [    0.969293] pnp 00:06: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0b00 (active) [   
0.969418] pnp 00:07: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0303 (active) [    0.969528] pnp 00:08: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs SYN1e3f SYN1e00 SYN0002 PNP0f13 (active) [    0.969969] system 00:09: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0c02 (active) [    0.970574] system 00:0a: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0c01 (active) [    0.970617] pnp: PnP ACPI: found 11 devices [    0.970622] ACPI: ACPI bus type pnp unregistered [    1.138064] ACPI: Deprecated procfs I/F for AC is loaded, please retry with CONFIG_ACPI_PROCFS_POWER cleared [   
1.138331] ACPI: AC Adapter [ACAD] (off-line) [    1.139068] ACPI: Lid Switch [LID0] [    1.139176] ACPI: Power Button [PWRB] [    1.139286] ACPI: Power Button [PWRF] [    1.144637] ACPI: Thermal Zone [TZ01] (0 C) [    1.144677] ACPI: Deprecated procfs I/F for battery is loaded, please retry with CONFIG_ACPI_PROCFS_POWER cleared [    1.144693] ACPI: Battery Slot [BAT0] (battery present) [    1.206926] ACPI: Battery Slot [BAT0] (battery present) [   13.176993] acpi device:1a: registered as cooling_device4 [   13.179931] acpi device:1b: registered as cooling_device5 [   13.180221] ACPI: Video Device [VGA] (multi-head: yes  rom: no  post: no) [   13.219589] acpi device:20: registered as cooling_device6 [   13.220851] ACPI: Video Device [GFX0] (multi-head: yes  rom: no  post: no) [ 1649.915134] i8042 aux 00:08: wake-up capability disabled by ACPI [ 1649.915147] i8042 kbd 00:07: wake-up capability enabled by ACPI [ 1650.931028] r8169 0000:03:00.0: wake-up capability enabled by ACPI [ 1650.954743] ehci_hcd 0000:00:1d.0: wake-up capability enabled by ACPI [ 1650.978733] ehci_hcd 0000:00:1a.0: wake-up capability enabled by ACPI [
1651.010950] ACPI: Preparing to enter system sleep state S3 [ 1652.251505] ACPI: Low-level resume complete [ 1652.360953] ACPI: Waking up from system sleep state S3 [ 1652.427581] ehci_hcd 0000:00:1a.0: wake-up capability disabled by ACPI [ 1652.435579] ehci_hcd 0000:00:1d.0: wake-up capability disabled by ACPI [
1652.437887] r8169 0000:03:00.0: wake-up capability disabled by ACPI [ 1652.506660] i8042 kbd 00:07: wake-up capability disabled by ACPI [ 1661.238234] ACPI Error: No handler for Region [CMS0] (ffff8801d5035558) [SystemCMOS] (20110623/evregion-373) [ 1661.238253] ACPI Error: Region SystemCMOS (ID=5) has no handler (20110623/exfldio-292) [ 1661.238268] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_SB_.PCI0.LPCB.EC0_._Q33] (Node ffff8801d5054de8), AE_NOT_EXIST (20110623/psparse-536) [ 3151.784288] i8042 aux 00:08: wake-up capability disabled by ACPI [ 3151.784301] i8042 kbd 00:07: wake-up capability enabled by ACPI [ 3152.797676] r8169 0000:03:00.0: wake-up capability enabled by ACPI [ 3152.821379] ehci_hcd 0000:00:1d.0: wake-up capability enabled by ACPI [
3152.845367] ehci_hcd 0000:00:1a.0: wake-up capability enabled by ACPI [ 3152.877600] ACPI: Preparing to enter system sleep state S3 [
3154.313213] ACPI: Low-level resume complete [ 3154.422297] ACPI: Waking up from system sleep state S3 [ 3154.489692] ehci_hcd 0000:00:1a.0: wake-up capability disabled by ACPI [ 3154.497667] ehci_hcd 0000:00:1d.0: wake-up capability disabled by ACPI [
3154.505947] r8169 0000:03:00.0: wake-up capability disabled by ACPI [ 3154.568985] i8042 kbd 00:07: wake-up capability disabled by ACPI [ 3162.745149] ACPI Error: No handler for Region [CMS0] (ffff8801d5035558) [SystemCMOS] (20110623/evregion-373) [ 3162.745168] ACPI Error: Region SystemCMOS (ID=5) has no handler (20110623/exfldio-292) [ 3162.745183] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_SB_.PCI0.LPCB.EC0_._Q33] (Node ffff8801d5054de8), AE_NOT_EXIST (20110623/psparse-536) [ 6775.723501] ACPI Error: No handler for Region [CMS0] (ffff8801d5035558) [SystemCMOS] (20110623/evregion-373) [ 6775.723519] ACPI Error: Region SystemCMOS (ID=5) has no handler (20110623/exfldio-292) [ 6775.723535] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_SB_.PCI0.LPCB.EC0_._Q33] (Node ffff8801d5054de8), AE_NOT_EXIST (20110623/psparse-536) [10388.004760] ACPI Error: No handler for Region [CMS0] (ffff8801d5035558) [SystemCMOS] (20110623/evregion-373) [10388.004778] ACPI Error: Region SystemCMOS (ID=5) has no handler (20110623/exfldio-292) [10388.004801] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_SB_.PCI0.LPCB.EC0_._Q33] (Node ffff8801d5054de8), AE_NOT_EXIST (20110623/psparse-536) [10723.591930] i8042 aux 00:08: wake-up capability disabled by ACPI [10723.591942] i8042 kbd 00:07: wake-up capability enabled by ACPI [10724.607624] r8169 0000:03:00.0: wake-up capability enabled by ACPI [10724.631349] ehci_hcd 0000:00:1d.0: wake-up capability enabled by ACPI [10724.655339] ehci_hcd 0000:00:1a.0: wake-up capability enabled by ACPI [10724.687572] ACPI: Preparing to enter system sleep state S3 [10726.123176] ACPI: Low-level resume complete [10726.232181] ACPI: Waking up from system sleep state S3 [10726.303653] ehci_hcd 0000:00:1a.0: wake-up capability disabled by ACPI [10726.311648] ehci_hcd 0000:00:1d.0: wake-up capability disabled by ACPI [10726.315734] r8169 0000:03:00.0: wake-up capability disabled by ACPI [10726.379287] i8042 kbd 00:07: wake-up capability disabled by ACPI [10734.393523] ACPI Error: No handler for Region [CMS0] (ffff8801d5035558) [SystemCMOS] (20110623/evregion-373) [10734.393542] ACPI Error: Region SystemCMOS (ID=5) has no handler (20110623/exfldio-292) [10734.393557] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_SB_.PCI0.LPCB.EC0_._Q33] (Node ffff8801d5054de8), AE_NOT_EXIST (20110623/ps
```

Continuous sound from the fan is very annoying, any help would highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

installing the graphic card drivers help me fight the continuous sound from fan and also my laptop battery lasts more around 60 minutes more :)